# Combine named numeric vector and data.frame

Tags: r

I have a dataframe `pr` and a vector `f11`

```
pr <- structure(list(value = c(21, 4, 75, 
14), site = c("ra", "ce", "ze", 
"ste")), row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4"), class = "data.frame")

f11 <- c(ze = 54, ra = 7,ce = 63, ste = 36)
```

I want to have this output for each site (the order of sites is not important):

```
      value           site

     (21-7)/100      re
     (4-63)/100      ce
     (75-54)/100      ze
     (14-36)/100      ste
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can subset the vector `f11` using `pr$site`.
So the final solution could be

```
pr$value <- (pr$value - f11[pr$site]) / 100
```